# Drupal 9 - custom module caching issue

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

Longtime D7 user, first time with D9. I am writing my first custom module and having a devil of a time. My routing calls a controller that simple does this:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
die("hello A -  ". rand());
```

I can refresh the page over and over and get a new random number each

time. But, when I change the code to:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
die("hello B -  ". rand());
```

I still get "hello *A* 34234234" for several minutes. Clearing the cache doesn't help, all I can do is wait, it's normally about two minutes. I am at my wits end.

I thought it maybe an issue with my docker instance. So I generated a simple HTML file but if I edit then reload that file changes are reflected immediately.

In my settings.local.php I have disabled the render cache, caching for migrations, Internal Page Cache, and Dynamic Page Cache.

In my mymod.routing.yml I have:

```
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    no_cache: TRUE
```

Any hint on what I am missing would be deeply appreciated.

thanks,
summer

Comment: This seems like an opcode caching issue (opcode cache keeps a copy of the compiled script in memory).

Comment: Thanks! you are exactly right it was opcache.enable =1 in my php.ini file. I just couldn't see it last night.